# Connection between categorical, topological and algebraical sections?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, category-theory, terminology, definition

I am studying Lie group representations and came accross a term "section". Before, I didn´t know it can also have algebraic meaning. Neither I could find any sufficient definition for sections in abstract algebra or group theory.

Are "algebraic sections" related to other definitions of sections, or is it completely different concept? What is the precise definition?

Thank you.

Summary:

**1. Category theory**

**Definition**:  Right inverse of some morphism

---

**2. Topology**

**Section also called:** cross section, section of a fiber bundle

**Definition**: Section of a fiber bundle E is a continuous right inverse of the projection function $\pi$ . So it is the map from a base space back to the fiber bundle.

---

**3. Abstract algebra**

**Section also called:** subquotient

**Definition**: ?

Comment: Sections you see in algebra are the categorical sections. In the meanwhile, the terminology of these were inspired (I assume) by the topological sections, as a topological section really just gives you a "section" of the geometry object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *section* in the context of homological algebra is the following. If we have a short exact sequence of Lie algebras
$$
0\rightarrow I \rightarrow L\xrightarrow{f} Q \rightarrow 0,
$$
then a *section* is a map $g\colon Q\rightarrow L$ with $f\circ g={\rm id}_Q$. If this is a Lie algebra homomorphism then the short exact sequence splits.

Other references at this site:

[Section of a short exact sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808816/section-of-a-short-exact-sequence)